Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21
my jdk version is 17, also set it on everywhere but build fails and return this message: Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21 What should I do?
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':assets_audio_player_web:compileDebugKotlin'.
> Error while evaluating property 'compilerOptions.jvmTarget' of task ':assets_audio_player_web:compileDebugKotlin'.
   > Failed to calculate the value of property 'jvmTarget'.
      > Unknown Kotlin JVM target: 21



Did you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79012911/unknown-kotlin-jvm-target-21-flutter-build-error-in-beginner-project?rq=2 and set your sourceCompatibility?

compileOptions {
coreLibraryDesugaringEnabled true
    sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
    targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
}

kotlinOptions {
    jvmTarget = "17"
}

yes this is my side
